# Understanding models in a PHP MVC - splitting in multiple classes?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I am reading a lot of articles of PHP MVC use lately and found out I was programming my CMS all wrong...
Apparently the model-layer of an MVC contains multiple class instances to pass on data.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to apply this technique to my case. I hope you can help me shed light to the case:

```
class site_model {
    private $iSite_id;
    private $sSite_name;
    //+ 8 other variables

    function __construct($iSite_id = null, $sSite_name = null) {
        $this->iSite_id= $iSite_id;
        $this->sSite_name = $sSite_name;
    }

    public function get_all_sites() {
        $aList = [];
        $sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM sites WHERE 1';
        $mReturn = mysql_query($sSQL);  

        while($aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($mResult)) {
            $aList[] = new site_model($aRow['site_id'], $['site_name']);
        }

        return $aList;
    }

    //+ 20 other query functions
} 


class site_controller {
    private $oSiteModel;

    public function return_all_sites() {
        $oSiteModel = new site_model();

        return $oSiteModel->get_all_sites();
    }
 }
```

What I am worried about is when I create an array of model objects that contain a lot of db-functions (20+), and I don't even need most of the functions, I am loading a lot of useless data into the memory? I have no idea how much extra memory that is, but if I can avoid it, I think I should?

**A few questions:**

1. Is it good practice to store all the query-functions into the model?
2. If I load multiple instances of the model object, does the memory load in all these db-functions per instance or do they share the same functions stored in memory?
   [I ask this because it's important to me to keep performance up, and I don't want to consume unnecessary resources]
3. Is using a separate db_model class the right way to go? With this I mean a model (data) just for setting and getting data and applying validations, and use another model(db) to contain all db functions and let the controller call the right db functions to set the data-model?
4. Ia it good practice to use a db-API class to execute the functions with data retrieved from models instead of the (db)model for better encapsulation and code reuse?

Like:

```
interface DatabaseAdapter
{
    public function connect();
    public function disconnect();

    public function prepare($sql, array $options = array());
    public function execute(array $parameters = array());

    public function fetch($fetchStyle = null, 
        $cursorOrientation = null, $cursorOffset = null);
    public function fetchAll($fetchStyle = null, $column = 0);

    public function select($table, array $bind, 
        $boolOperator = "AND");
    public function insert($table, array $bind);
    public function update($table, array $bind, $where = "");
    public function delete($table, $where = "");

    //.. extra functions here for custom queries like joins etc..
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping me become a better programmer :)

Comment: You should atleast, create a base model class that contains query logic and common methods like findAll, etc. Have a look what other popular MVC frameworks are doing (For example https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent )

Comment: And no need to reinvent the wheel (DatabaseAdapter), just use PDO instead of old mysql_* functions!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, can you maybe answer one of the questions specifically?